# what should not be included in public repo of flutter app

Tags: git, flutter, gitignore

I am just started with Flutter. I made an app in flutter. Now, I want to put this app in my github public repo. My question is what should I put in .gitignore file?

I mean, what should not be included in public repo of flutter app?

Comment: How did you create your app? Didn't you use `flutter create` command? The command would have created the `.gitignore` file as well.

Comment: https://www.gitignore.io/api/flutter

Comment: https://www.gitignore.io/api/android,flutter,androidstudio

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/.gitignore

Comment: @phd yes, I used flutter create and .gitignore file is created but I added few files like json file to connect firebase etc. so I am curious what should be not included in public repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.gitignore` file contents from a newly created flutter app. Theses are the files which are to be excluded from git.

```
# Miscellaneous
*.class
*.log
*.pyc
*.swp
.DS_Store
.atom/
.buildlog/
.history
.svn/

# IntelliJ related
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
.idea/

# Visual Studio Code related
.vscode/

# Flutter/Dart/Pub related
**/doc/api/
.dart_tool/
.flutter-plugins
.packages
.pub-cache/
.pub/
/build/

# Android related
**/android/**/gradle-wrapper.jar
**/android/.gradle
**/android/captures/
**/android/gradlew
**/android/gradlew.bat
**/android/local.properties
**/android/**/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java

# iOS/XCode related
**/ios/**/*.mode1v3
**/ios/**/*.mode2v3
**/ios/**/*.moved-aside
**/ios/**/*.pbxuser
**/ios/**/*.perspectivev3
**/ios/**/*sync/
**/ios/**/.sconsign.dblite
**/ios/**/.tags*
**/ios/**/.vagrant/
**/ios/**/DerivedData/
**/ios/**/Icon?
**/ios/**/Pods/
**/ios/**/.symlinks/
**/ios/**/profile
**/ios/**/xcuserdata
**/ios/.generated/
**/ios/Flutter/App.framework
**/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
**/ios/Flutter/Generated.xcconfig
**/ios/Flutter/app.flx
**/ios/Flutter/app.zip
**/ios/Flutter/flutter_assets/
**/ios/ServiceDefinitions.json
**/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.*

# Exceptions to above rules.
!**/ios/**/default.mode1v3
!**/ios/**/default.mode2v3
!**/ios/**/default.pbxuser
!**/ios/**/default.perspectivev3
!/packages/flutter_tools/test/data/dart_dependencies_test/**/.packages
```

Comment: I have the same .gitignore content generated automatically then why would build folder in my project would check-in? Now each project in git is around 300MB in size. I use Android Studio for development & do not use `flutter create` command for new projects.

Comment: Perhaps your build folder is deep inside? Try `**/build/` instead of `/build/`